# API controller can't be found in browser in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am so new in `single page application`.i create a `webapi`as you can see here :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class ManageStudentInforAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private SchoolManagementEntities db = new SchoolManagementEntities();

        // GET: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI  
        public IQueryable<Student> Get()
        {
            return db.Students;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i call this url `http://localhost:5411/ManageStudentInforAPI` the result is

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /ManageStudentInforAPI
```

Where is my problem .any details you need i can post.i am using vs2015

[image]

Comment: Please add you routing configuration. Default the api is reached `api/controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try calling the controller as http://localhost:5411/Api/ManageStudentInforAPI
this should work

Comment: I get this error:This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: Why the result isn't returned?

Answer (score 2):

You've missed `api` before `ManageStudentInforAPI`. Try to replace your URL by `http://localhost:5411/api/ManageStudentInforAPI`

Or you can add `[Route("route")]` to your controller or method and call `http://localhost:5411/api/route`

Answer (score 1):

Call your api like this `http://localhost:5411/api/ManageStudentInforAPI`

or if you want custom api url then you can set route like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class ManageStudentInforAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private SchoolManagementEntities db = new SchoolManagementEntities();

        // GET: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI
        [Route("api/MyApi")]
        public IQueryable<Student> Get()
        {
            return db.Students;
        }
    }
}
```

then Call your api like this `http://localhost:5411/api/MyApi`